# Python: output for recursively printing out files and folders

Tags: python

I have written a python function that recursively prints out files and folders, but now I am not sure how to display it in an aesthetic manner (in plain text). How do you display your folder structures?

Comment: indent the directories and files names using whitespaces or whatever you want...what is the *specific* problem? Do you except a hint "indent it in red or green"?

Comment: Come on folks, a little originality here. I'm sure there is more than indents that can be useful. OP is looking "aesthetics", use your imagination!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write a function to return the directory structure as a nested list like this:

```
['DIR1/',['fileA','fileB','DIR3/',['fileE','fileF']],'DIR2/',['fileC','fileD']]
```

then you could use `pprint.pformat` to create a passable string representation:

```
import pprint
import textwrap
import re

data=['DIR1/',['fileA','fileB','DIR3/',['fileE','fileF']],'DIR2/',['fileC','fileD']]
print(textwrap.dedent(re.sub(r"[\]\[',]", r' ',
                             pprint.pformat(data,indent=4,width=1))))
```

yields

```
DIR1/  
    fileA  
    fileB  
    DIR3/  
        fileE  
        fileF    
DIR2/  
    fileC  
    fileD
```

Note: The above code assumes your file and directory names do not contain any of the characters `,[]'`...

Comment: how would that function look like? :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a text-only command-line display or in a GUI?

For command-line display, just use a recursive function passing an "indentation" variable to recursive calls, increasing it for each level:

```
toplevel/
   level2/
      file.txt
      file2.txt
   level2_again/
      file3.txt
```

For a GUI - use a widget provided by the relevant framework. For example, with `PyQt` there's the `QTreeView` widget.

Comment: Sorry, it will be a text-only output.